# Flutter HMAC SHA1 encoding

Tags: flutter, hmac, hmacsha1, opendata

I'm a newbie in Flutter who don't know a lot about HMAC code. I want to get datas from an online opendata interface, and I wonder how to use Flutter's functions to encode the parameters and complete my authorization, such as my key, my ID, and x-date. Showed below is the example format provided by the opendata interface website. Would somebody teach me how to encode those parameters in the form of it? Grateful for everyone who spends time trying to answer my question!!

**Key   Value**
Authorization   hmac username="APP ID", algorithm="hmac-sha1", headers="x-date", signature="Base64(HMAC-SHA1("x-date: " + x-date , APP Key))"

**x-date**
Wed, 19 Apr 2017 08:37:50 GMT

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl0nO.png)

Comment: Use `pointycastle` - tutorial here: https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart/blob/master/tutorials/hmac.md

Comment: @Richard Heap Tks man, I'll check it out.